# Check understanding of definition of differential

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have these two definitions I'm trying to make sense about.

Let the function $f$ be defined and differentiable in the set $D$ of real numbers, and $x \in D$.

**Definition I:** The function $\Delta f(x):h \to f(x+h)-f(x)$ defined for those values of h for which $x+h \in D$ is called increasing of $f$ in $x$.

**Definition II:** The function $df(x):h \to f'(x)h$ defined for every $h\in \mathbf R$ is called differential of $f$ in $x$. Since $dx=h$ we can rewrite the $h$ in any differential in the following form:
df(x)=f'(x)dx.

**My understanding** is the following:

The way I see it those functions are actually operators working on some function space of differentiable and defined in D functions.

The first one just tells the difference in the function values $f(x+h)-f(x)$.

The second one I see as an operator which gives approximation of the function value with a given step h. The only thing I can think of as an analogy is some numeric method for differential equation where we approximate the function value at the $x+h$ point by using the derivative at the point $x$ multiplied by the step.

Is this reasoning so far correct? What else might enrich my understanding of the definiition?

Comment: Hopefully you get another answer, I haven't seen these definitions.  They are roughly equivalent in specific circumstances to definitions I have seen.  However, you are mostly correct.  But $df(x)$ doesn't approximate $f$ at $x$.  It approximates how $f$ changes.  Note that if $f(x_0)$ is very large but $f'(x_0)$ is very small, then $f'(x)h$ is not going to be close to $f(x_0)$.  You could say that $f(x)+f'(x)h$ approximates $f$ near $x$.

Comment: I haven't really seen what you call $\Delta f(x)$ before. However, what you call $df(x)$ I've seen before called $df_x$, as the differential in differential geometry: it is a linear map between tangent spaces at the point $x$. However, since everything here is over $\mathbb{R}$, $df_x$ is just a linear map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is multiplication by the number $f'(x)$. If you think of $x$ as being time, then $df_x$ is kind of like freezing time at the point $x$, and checking how the quantity $f(x)$ is changing at that point in time.